# Android: Fail to connect to camera service at Camera.open() samsung galaxy note 2

Tags: android, camera

I have problem with camera on Galaxy Note 2 only.
When I call camera.open(), i catch this exception :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:343)
android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:318)
com.highconnexion.android.promolife.zbar.Activity_ZbarVerifyBarcode.getCameraInstance(Activity_ZbarVerifyBarcode.java:547)
com.highconnexion.android.promolife.zbar.Activity_ZbarVerifyBarcode$5.run(Activity_ZbarVerifyBarcode.java:284)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I have permissions in Manifest and my code works fine on other devices.

Thanks.

Comment: Show the associated call. Maybe you're trying to open the wrong camera index

Comment: It's ok, i just reboot the device and it works. Yesterday I had a crash on Camera application, so I think it's the problem.

Comment: So it was that you didn't correctly release the camera. It will happen again and again if you don't call the release() method

Comment: I call the release method before call Camera.open()

Comment: You shouldn't do it this way. Release means when you're done with the camera, free the associated lock. Open means you wan't to acquire the lock. If you acquire the lock, other apps couldn't use the camera anymore

Comment: I release camera in onDestroy() ok

Comment: You should do it in onPause() and open it in onResume()  or you will leak the camera lock

Answer (score 0):

If in your case is get crash while using `Camera` from your App.

It means the camera can not `release()` correctly in `onPause()` or `onDestroy()`.

Two methods above can not be called in case application get crash.

So the way fix it should be reboot & re-install application.

It should fix your issue.